# All Laravel routes are not found (404 error) on https://proclubs.app/login

Tags: laravel, nginx, ssl, routes, digital-ocean

I have deployed my Laravel app to the following url proclubs.app - this is a domain from Google domains that requires an SSL certificate (the SSL has been setup using Certbot).

I have setup the Laravel Breeze package for authentication (e.g register/login functionality) and this all works fine when testing locally, now I have pushed this to a remote URL none of the routes don't work, and I just get a `404 Not Found` message. I have ran the `php artisan route:list` and can see all the expected routes are there. I am 99% certain I have made a mistake with the nginx server block - I have used the default one that digitalocean provide in `etc/nginx/sites-available` and edited it accordingly, but not sure what is incorrect for me to get these 404 errors, can anyone suggest what I have done wrong?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/proclubs/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Laravel related only
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name proclubs.app www.proclubs.app;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


server {

    root /var/www/proclubs/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name proclubs.app www.proclubs.app; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/proclubs.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/proclubs.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}

server {
    if ($host = www.proclubs.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = proclubs.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80  ;
    server_name proclubs.app www.proclubs.app;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

-- Expected behaviour --

When a user visits the webpage `https://proclubs.app/login` OR `https://proclubs.app/login` I expect to see the Laravel Breeze default login page.

-- Actual Behaviour --

When I visit `https://proclubs.app/login` I just see a `404 Not Found` nginx error instead & no routes are working.

p.s i am confused why I have 3 server blocks too...

Server - `nginx/1.18.0 (Ubunto 20.04) on DigitalOcean LEMP droplet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get 404, probably requested path wrong. I checked your nginx configurations and I see you have 2 servers, for http (first server) and https (second server) requests.

When you enter the url /login path it means that you want to go login folder. But in laravel it is special request.

So your mistake is in the second server (https) your request find a folder, not a special request. You must change your location option with the first server location option.

```
location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
```

Change with

```
location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```